# Critical Ising T transformation

Tags: conformal-field-theory, ising-model, textbook-erratum

How can the following be consistent?

The $T$ transformation of a Virasoro character $\chi(q)$ of central charge $c$ and weight $h$ is given by
$$\chi(q+1) =e^{2 \pi i (h - c/24)}\chi(q)$$
for instance see eqn (125) [in Jean-Bernard Zuber's Introduction to Conformal Field Theory](https://www.lpthe.jussieu.fr/~zuber/MesPapiers/zako.pdf).

On the other hand, the $c = 1/2$ character $\chi_{1,2}(q)$ which is supposed to be one chiral half the Ising spin operator has $h = 1/16$ and
$$\chi_{1,2}(\tau + 1) = e^{i \pi/8}\chi_{1,2}(\tau)$$
according to the big yellow book. This appears to be missing the factor of $e^{-2\pi i c/24}$.... what happened?

There must be something obvious I'm missing here.

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Comment: Did you mean $\tau\to\tau+1$? It follows straightforwardly from the fact that all weights in the module differ by integers, and doesn't depend on the module being short.

Comment: Thanks @PeterKravchuk my bad. And I agree. It's just a mistake in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've decided this must be a typo in the big yellow book (di Fracesco et al). The proper transformation rule should be
$$\chi_{1,2}(q+1) = e^{2\pi i/24}\chi_{1,2}(q).$$
I was worried since $\chi_{1,2}$ is not quite the same as the Verma module $V_{2,1}$ (which is reducible), the transformation rule I quoted might become modified. Actually it doesn't, as one can see looking at table 8.1 in the big yellow book:

[image]

One can compute $h_{1,2} = 1/16$ and derive the correct transformation rule with exponent $1/16 - 1/48 = 1/24$.

Edit: note in this table they've exchanged $p$ with $p'$ and $r$ with $s$ so my $\chi_{1,2}$ is $\chi_{2,1}$ in the table, annoyingly.